# Toggle div through multiple <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am able to toggle through a js function that uses href id for matching to the corresponding div or td to toggle.

But My goal is to be able to toggle the div/td with another href that is found at the bottom of the page. This href contains the same id and name.

Here is an example:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8U82/15/) (The toggle function works in my remote server but it doesn't somehow in jsfiddle)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showonlyonev2(thechosenone) {
      var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
            name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("name");
            if (name == 'newboxes-2') {
                  if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                        if (newboxes[x].style.display == 'block') {
                              newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        else {
                              newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                        }
                  }else {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                  }
            }
      }
}​
</script>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px;">
            <a id="myHeader1-2" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes1-2');" >toggle</a>
         </div>
         <div name="newboxes-2" id="newboxes1-2" name="div1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px;">Div #1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px;">
            <a id="myHeader2-2" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes2-2');" >toggle</a>
         </div>
         <div name="newboxes-2" id="newboxes2-2" name="div2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px;">Div #2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px;">
            <a id="myHeader3-2" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes3-2');" >toggle</a>
         </div>
         <div name="newboxes-2" id="newboxes3-2" name="div3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px;">Div #3</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>


<div style="padding-top:20px;">
    <a id="myHeader1-2" name="div1" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes1-2');">See Div #1</a>  
</div>    

<div style="padding-top:20px;">
    <a id="myHeader2-2" name="div2" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes2-2');">See Div #2</a>  
</div>

<div style="padding-top:20px;">
    <a id="myHeader3-2" name="div3" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes3-2');">See Div #3</a>  
</div>    ​
```

Comment: It was not working because you had it set to onload, not in the head/body. [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8U82/16/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unusual to have a "name" attribute on a div.

The divs in the top table have 2 "name" attributes each.

I would clean it up and try again.